# Why is my username user20445 in this SE site while in all other SE websites it is "aminabzz"?

Tags: support

Why is my username user20445 in this SE site while in all other SE websites it is "aminabzz"?

Comment: I have no idea why your name is different.  The ELL moderation team didn't change your name, at any rate.  I suppose it must be some sort of bug?

Comment: @snailcar I think the system hiccups every now and then. I see OP's username as aminabzz; was that you or did the issue fix itself?

Comment: I contacted SE. they received a ticket from me and fixed it for me. @M.A.R.